# Java Regex Identifying Non-Consecutive Pairs of Characters/Numbers

Tags: regex

I'm looking to pick out pairs of word characters in a string, that may not necessarily be beside each other in the string. For example, "ahna32g" should match, due to the pair of 'a' characters. What I currently have is `"\w*(\w)\1+\w*"` which is successful if the matching characters are consecutive. I'm quite new to regular expressions, so if a detailed explanation could be given I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to insert `\w*` between `(\w)` and `\1` to let the regex engine match any 0+ word chars in between the repeating chars:

```
\w*(\w)\w*\1+\w*
       ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/InNnI3/1).

So, the regex will match

- `\w*` - 0+ word chars
- `(\w)` - capture a word char into Group 1
- `\w*` - will match 0+ word chars
- `\1+` - one or more occurrences of the value inside Group 1
- `\w*` - 0+ word chars.

Comment: The `+` in `\1+` appears superfluous.

Comment: @linden2015 You are right, the `+` quantifier is not necessary. But it does not do any harm here.

Answer (score 0):

My approach captures the (earliest) repeated characters in group 1 and 2. It's also less steps than the already posted answer.

`\w*?(\w)(?=\w*?(\1))\w*`

```
\w*? // 0 or more word chars, lazily matched
(\w) // a word char (as group 1)
(?=  // look ahead and assert a match of:
\w*? // 0 or more word chars, lazily matched
(\1) // group 1 (as group 2)
)    // end of assertion
\w*  // 0 or more word chars
```

- Flags: g

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/d6coAO/3)

Comment: It seems that you pay too much attention to the number of steps at the http://regex101.com. Really, it is a good idea, but there are 2 things to keep in mind: 1) the number of steps does not really prove a regex is efficient or not (the efficiency must be checked only in the target environment), 2) the lazy quantifier with the first `\w*?` is no better than the greedy one in real world: see [your regex](https://regex101.com/r/BHX6P7/1) (690 steps) and [mine with the same samples](https://regex101.com/r/BHX6P7/2) (53 steps). In different cases, different greediness will perform better.

Comment: (And there is no real need to use a lookaround here, `(?=\w*?(\1))` can be turned into `\w*?\1` and the pattern will look like `\w*?(\w)\w*?\1\w*`. Oh, it will even be more efficient on [the test  set in the comment above :)](https://regex101.com/r/BHX6P7/3)).

Comment: I think your long word that matches already at the end is skewing in favor of your pattern. If I change the sample a little bit mine remains faster: [mine](https://regex101.com/r/d6coAO/4), [yours](https://regex101.com/r/InNnI3/2). I haven't gotten to the chapter yet (of Mastering Regular Expressions) about optimizing, so I still have that to learn, but I'm not convinced of your argument yet! The point is taken however about real world performance testing.